# Call approve function() doesn't work

Tags: web3js, dapps

```
myContractInstance.methods.approve('0x...', 300).call(function(error, approve){
        if(error){console.log(error)};

        if(approve){console.log("allowance for this address :"+ approve)};
        //$('#allowanceAmount').text(allowance);
})})};
```

Hi, what's the problem with the function? It doesn't work.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Function `approve` is not constant (neither `pure` nor `view`).

You should therefore execute it using `send` instead of `call`.